# XML parsing only some nodes - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following example XML:

```
<PRODUCTRATINGLIST>
  <PRODUCT>
    <VENDORREF>AC308A~</VENDORREF>
    <RATING>100%</RATING>
    <REVIEWCOUNT>7</REVIEWCOUNT>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT>
    <VENDORREF>AC308C~</VENDORREF>
    <RATING>98%</RATING>
    <REVIEWCOUNT>89</REVIEWCOUNT>
  </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTRATINGLIST>
```

I'm simply trying to extract each node under PRODUCT:

```
$ratings = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

foreach ($ratings->PRODUCT as $rating){
  $part = $rating->VENDORREF;
  $rating = str_replace('%','',$rating->RATING);
  $numReviews = $rating->REVIEWCOUNT;
}
```

If I then try to print each element e.g.

```
echo $part.' '.$rating.' '.$numReviews;
```

`$numReviews` is always blank and I have no idea why.

Comment: You are using rating as a variable $rating = str_replace('%','',$rating->RATING);  if you change it to even $Rating, you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the $rating array with a variable, fix it like this:

```
$part = $rating->VENDORREF;
$rating_string = str_replace('%','',$rating->RATING);
$numReviews = $rating->REVIEWCOUNT;
```

Comment: I see that Jim already posted this as a comment to your question, sorry for that!

Comment: God damn, can stare at code all day and not see the obvious sometimes! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. You change the variable names.

```
$ratings = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

foreach ($ratings->PRODUCT as $rating){
    $part = $rating->VENDORREF;
    $ratingVal = str_replace('%','',$rating->RATING);
    $numReviews = $rating->REVIEWCOUNT;
}

echo $part.' '.$ratingVal.' '.$numReviews;
```